# xargs how to string commands together

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, xargs

Hey guys im a newbie scripter with no formal training in programming so apologies in advance for the messy code.

What I want to accomplish:

This what directories look like.

```
/home/AAA 

/home/BBB 

/home/CCC

/home/AAA/aaaa.S01.aaa

/home/AAA/zzzz.S02.zzz

/home/AAA/xxx.S03.xxx

/home/AAA/aaaa.S01.aaa/bbbb.s01e01.bbbb.mkv
```

I want to make a torrent of directory AAA, cd two levels into it, make mediainfo file of first .mkv, make thumbnails of same file, cd to AAA, mkdir files, move all jpg, txt and torrent file from sub directories to files. Do the same thing with BBB and CCC and so on. Its all tv shows, so general naming scheme is parent directory with tv.show1,tv.show2 etc. Every tv show has seasons starting with season 1 and have S01 in the directory name and within each season folder there are mkv files which follow standard naming structure i.e s01e01,s01e02

I made a script that works only if there is one subdirectory. Im sure im using xargs all wrong but it seems to do the trick. Can someone help me fix this and the run the whole command as a loop on every directory thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

ls | xargs -I {} mktorrent -p -v -l 24 -a https://tracker/announce -o {}.torrent {} && rm privatehd.sh.torrent && cd *S0* && mediainfo *01* > mediainfo.txt && ffmpeg -ss 00:03:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb.jpg && ffmpeg -ss 00:09:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb1.jpg && ffmpeg -ss 00:15:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb2.jpg && ffmpeg -ss 00:18:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb3.jpg && ffmpeg -ss 00:20:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb4.jpg && cd ../ && mkdir phd && mv **/*.jpg ./phd && mv **/*.txt ./phd && mv *.torrent ./phd && mv **/*.ass ./phd
```

What it does

```
ls | xargs -I {} mktorrent -p -v -l 24 -a https://tracker/announce -o {}.torrent {}
```

makes torrent of every subdirectory but the way im using it now is the one folder and .sh file

```
&& rm privatehd.sh.torrent
```

removes extra.torrent file

```
&& cd *S0* && mediainfo *01* > mediainfo.txt
```

cd to folder containing string S0 this needs to changed to S01 to work with new files, generates mediainfo for file containing string 01 and saves to txt

```
&& ffmpeg -ss 00:03:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb.jpg && ffmpeg -ss 00:09:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb1.jpg && ffmpeg -ss 00:15:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb2.jpg && ffmpeg -ss 00:18:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb3.jpg && ffmpeg -ss 00:20:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb4.jpg
```

makes 5 thumbnails from various timestamps using ffmpeg

```
 && cd ../ && mkdir phd && mv **/*.jpg **/*.txt *.torrent ./phd
```

clean up. cd up one level make new directory, move files generated to that directory.

```
&& mv **/*.ass ./phd
```

command kept failing so i added this and it worked but i think i didnt use {} at the end thats why? but adding this nonsense made everything before it run ok and failed at this. which didnt matter.

As I mentioned im a horrible scripter. Have spent hours trying to figure out a way which will let me use the command as a loop on every subdirectory of parent. But will need to cd 2 levels instead of one like in the example.

Not sure this makes sense, am happy to provide more info.

Thanks

this is before and after running the script i made on a single directory.
before https://prnt.sc/u3ul9s
after https://prnt.sc/u3ullj
https://prnt.sc/u3ulph

Answer (score 1):

Stringing many commands together with `&&` is bad form (becomes unredable very fast, and you cannot set variables, and its hard to add comments, as you see above). So

1. Make a script that uses a positional parameter to designate the directory to work on.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo Working on directory "$1"
```

2. One of the first line of the script can be a `set -e` to make the script exit in case of error (though in the long term it is better to check return codes)
3. Then you can put one statement per line

```
#! /bin/bash
set-e
echo Working on directory "$1"

mktorrent -p -v -l 24 -a https://tracker/announce -o "$1".torrent "$1"
rm privatehd.sh.torrent
cd *S0*
mediainfo *01* > mediainfo.txt
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb.jpg
ffmpeg -ss 00:09:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb1.jpg
ffmpeg -ss 00:15:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb2.jpg
ffmpeg -ss 00:18:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb3.jpg
ffmpeg -ss 00:20:45 -i *01* -vframes 1 -q:v 2 thumb4.jpg
cd ../
mkdir phd
mv **/*.jpg ./phd
mv **/*.txt ./phd
mv *.torrent ./phd
mv **/*.ass ./phd
```

4. Once you have the script working on one directory you can invoke it on several directories by entering in a command prompt:

```
for d in directorypattern*/; do the_script "$d" ; done
```

5. When the script works well, you can make the body of the script a function, and
   then add a line in the script to loop on the directories passed as several parameters

```
#! /bin/bash
function process_directory {
    echo Working on directory "$1"
    #  More code here
}

for dir in "$@"; 
do 
    process_directory "$dir"
done
```

Invoked as:

```
the_script_for_all_dirs directorypattern*/
```

Comment: 1) don't use *cd* in scripts, always check success *cd \*S0\* || exit 2* otherwise your script may run out of control especially when using *cd ..* and moving/deleting files! 2) *for loops* (on globs) should always test items before processing, like *[ -e "$d" ] || continue*

Comment: @alecxs: The `set -e` covers it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to ditch xargs and go for a simple loop with a few variable works like a charm but I went a bit overboard added colors, multiple torrents, multiple trackers etc. Programming is so much fun :D

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    set -e

    BLACK="\033[30m"
    RED="\033[31m"
    GREEN="\033[32m"
    YELLOW="\033[33m"
    BLUE="\033[34m"
    PINK="\033[35m"
    CYAN="\033[36m"
    WHITE="\033[37m"
    NORMAL="\033[0;39m"
    
    echo -e  $RED INITIALIZING TORRENT SCRIPT SIT TIGHT... 
    
    ls > list.txt
    
    sed -i '/list.txt/d' ./list.txt
    sed -i '/script.sh/d' ./list.txt
    
    for filename in $(cat list.txt); do
            echo -e $YELLOW STARTING $filename TORRENT HASH
        echo -e $WHITE
        date
        mktorrent -p -l 24 -a https://tracker.1/announce -o $filename.1.torrent "$filename" > /dev/null 2>&1
            echo -e $YELLOW PRIVATE HD $filename TORRENT HASHED
        echo -e $WHITE
        date
        mktorrent -p -l 24 -a https://tracker.2 -o $filename.2.torrent "$filename" > /dev/null 2>&1
            echo -e $YELLOW TORRENT LEECH $filename TORRENT HASHED
        echo -e $WHITE
        date
        mktorrent -p -l 24 -a https://tracker 3 -o $filename.3.torrent "$filename" > /dev/null 2>&1
            echo -e $YELLOW TORRENT DATABASE $filename TORRENT HASHED
        echo -e $WHITE
        date
        cd $filename
            ls > list.txt
            sed -i '/list.txt/d' ./list.txt
            line=$(head -n 1 list.txt)
            mediainfo $line > ./../$line.txt
        echo -e  $CYAN MEDIAINFO GENERATED
        ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:02:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.1.jpg
            ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:04:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.2.jpg
            ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:06:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.3.jpg
            echo -e  $BLUE 3/10 THUMBNAILS FOR $line GENERATED
        ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:08:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.4.jpg
            ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:10:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.5.jpg
            ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:12:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.6.jpg
            sleep 5
        echo -e  $PINK 6/10 THUMBNAILS FOR $line GENERATED
        ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:14:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.7.jpg
            ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:16:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.8.jpg
            ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:18:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.9.jpg
            sleep 5
        echo -e  $BLUE 9/10 THUMBNAILS FOR $line GENERATED
        ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:20:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.10.jpg
            sleep 5
        echo -e  $PINK FINISHINED GENERATING THUMBNAILS FOR $line
        cd ..
            sleep 5
        echo -e  $GREEN CLEANUP STARTED
        mkdir $filename.files
            cp *$line*.jpg ./$filename.files
            cp *$line.txt ./$filename.files
            cp $filename*.torrent ./$filename.files
            rm *$line*.jpg *$line.txt $filename*.torrent
        sleep 5
        echo -e  $GREEN CLEANUP DONE
        sleep 5
    done
    
    rm **/*list.txt
    rm list.txt
    echo -e $WHITE
    date
    echo -e  $RED TORRENT SCRIPT SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTED
    echo -e  $NORMAL
```

So this loop makes a torrent of directory, makes a mediainfo.txt, makes 10 thumbnails from first mkv. Finally makes a directory.files directory and moves generated files into that. cleans up extra files at the end.

**Explanation:**
Set color variables to use with echo -e

```
    BLACK="\033[30m"
    RED="\033[31m"
    GREEN="\033[32m"
    YELLOW="\033[33m"
    BLUE="\033[34m"
    PINK="\033[35m"
    CYAN="\033[36m"
    WHITE="\033[37m"
    NORMAL="\033[0;39m"
```

make a list of the contents of the starting directory and remove extra lines with sed

```
    ls > list.txt

    sed -i '/list.txt/d' ./list.txt
    sed -i '/script.sh/d' ./list.txt
```

start loop and set $filename variable from list.txt using cat

```
for filename in $(cat list.txt); do
```

Run mktorrent command send output to null to get rid of annoying copyright banner showing up N number of times.

```
mktorrent -p -l 24 -a https://tracker 3 -o $filename.3.torrent "$filename" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

CD one level down create another list of contents and sed then set a new variable $line which uses first line of the new list.

```
        cd $filename
        ls > list.txt
        sed -i '/list.txt/d' ./list.txt
        line=$(head -n 1 list.txt)
```

use the new variable to generate mediainfo and thumbnails of first mkv file

```
mediainfo $line > ./../$line.txt
echo -e  $CYAN MEDIAINFO GENERATED
ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -ss 00:02:45 -i $line -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ./../$line.1.jpg
```

cd back one directory mkdir $filename.suffix and move generated files into that before ending loop

```
      cd ..
            mkdir $filename.files
            cp *$line*.jpg ./$filename.files
            cp *$line.txt ./$filename.files
            cp $filename*.torrent ./$filename.files
            rm *$line*.jpg *$line.txt $filename*.torrent
done
```

cleanup list.txt files

```
 rm **/*list.txt
    rm list.txt
```

Comment: Your very generic `ls` is dangerous, if you get any unexpected file it will be included. Better have a pattern that list everything you need and not more. Using `ls` in scripts is fraught with peril.  You can restrict the match to directories by putting a `/` at the end. Then you can loop directly on that, no need to put the list in a file: `for dir in pattern_for_directories*/; do ... ; done`